# Why embed video is not by z-index?

Tags: html, css, video, youtube

My topbar is fixed with z-index: `10000000`.

My iframe, embed, object have z-index: `0`.

I don't understand why my videos are still above the topbar...

How can I fix that ?

Thanks

[image: YouTube Z-Index]

Comment: Do you have any (partially) transparent elements over the video?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the old youtube embed method and change some params (set `wmode` to `opaque`):

```
<object width="420" height="315">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/oHg5SJYRHA0?version=3&amp;hl=ru_RU"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="wmode" value="opaque"/>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed wmode="opaque" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/oHg5SJYRHA0?version=3&amp;hl=ru_RU" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="420" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
</object>
```

This should help.

Comment: "opaque"...very helpfull.. you saved me a lot of time...thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using flash player, you can use the [`wmode`](http://www.8bitrocket.com/2011/02/11/quick-guide-to-wmode-and-flash-embedding/) property to set `z-index` of the player eg set `wmode=opaque`

Comment: Okay thanks, but If I use `<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" frameborder="0">
</iframe>` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is related to the wmode attribute of the embed element... you can read [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html#main_Using_Window_Mode__wmode__values_) something, to overcome the problem you can add to the embed element wmode="transparent" or wmode="opaque"..

let me now ;)